# like.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to make facebook like button.when i click like.undefined $ is appearing in console.it should echo 22 value default value on click.

```js
function like_add(article_id) {
$.post('ajax/like_add.php', {article_id:article_id}, function(data){
    if(data == 'success')
    {
        like_get(article_id);
    }
    else
    {
        alert(data);
    }   

});
}

function like_get(article_id) {
$.post('ajax/like_get.php',{article_id:article_id}, function(data){
    $('#article_'+article_id+'_likes').text(data);


});
}
```

```html
foreach($articles as $article){

        echo '<li>',$article['article_title'],'</p><p><a class="like" href="#" 
        onclick="like_add(', $article['article_id'] ,');">Like</a>
        <span id="article_', $article['article_id'] ,'_like">', $art
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery reference?

Comment: Include jQuery on page. Make sure it is included before using it.

Comment: @Tushar yes i placed it.......VM614:29 Refused to connect to "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=1466917123661": URL was permanently blocked by the user..........error is this

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not included in current page.
You can include it with this code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Place it between `<body> </body>` before your code.
But also you can load it async way:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js";
script.onreadystatechange = handler;
script.onload = handler;
head.appendChild(script);

function handler() { console.log("jQuery loaded!"); }
```

`handler()` will be called when jQuery will be loaded.

Comment: VM614:29 Refused to connect to "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=1466917123661": URL was permanently blocked by the user

Comment: Try to use jQuery No Conflict Mode.

Comment: First call `jQuery.noConflict();` and then replace `$` with `jQuery` in your code.

Comment: jquery is loaded ....but functions are not working... like_add and like_get ...........could u pls tell me whats d error

Comment: Read my comments above. Try to use `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: should i place it after function start or before?

Comment: Place it in start of your code, but **do not forget** to change every `$` to `jQuery` in your code!

Comment: these functions are in different js file...like.js......should i place this code there ?

Comment: You should place it once on your page. Before all script are loaded.

Comment: "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=1466918076963":........this is console error m getting after changes

Comment: Try to read some tutorials about JavaScript. I cannot help you with your question.